# Как в input String метод Scanner записать два слова как переменную? Задача jetbrains academy

Tags: java, scanner

```
    package com.Scanner;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Scaner {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String name = scanner.nextLine(); //Nick
            int age = scanner.nextInt();// 25
            scanner.nextLine();
            String education = scanner.nextLine(); //secondary
            int experience = scanner.nextInt(); //3
            scanner.nextLine();
            String fusion dishes = scanner.nextLine();// не компилирует
            System.out.println("The form for Nick is completed. We will contact you if we need a chef that cooks fusion dishes");

Input мне нужно ввести 5 параметра
 name,
 age,
education,
experience, 
fusion dishes.
Output The form for Nick is completed. We will contact you if we need a chef that cooks fusion dishes.
```

Comment: Что вы под этим подразумеваете?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю зачем, но можно так:

```
    String fusion, dishes;
    fusion = dishes = scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: Aaa, начинаю понимать... вы хотите ввести 2 слова через пробел и чтобы они записались в разные переменные?

Comment: не помогает к сожалению

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = scanner.nextLine(); //Nick
        int age = scanner.nextInt();// 25
        scanner.nextLine();
        String education = scanner.nextLine(); //secondary
        int experience = scanner.nextInt(); //3
        scanner.nextLine();
        String fusion = scanner.nextLine();
        String fusionDishes = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("The form for " + name + " is completed. We will contact you if we need a chef that cooks " + fusionDishes);
    }
```

Рекомендую почитать основы java. Это очень простые задания, так дальше далеко не уедете.

Comment: Я читаю и делаю первые шаги в задачах. Но не все получается с первого раза. Спасибо

Comment: Не читает компилятор Ваш вариант fusionDishes.          Correct output:
The form for Eugene is completed. We will contact you if we need a chef that cooks fusion dishes.

Your code output:
The form for Eugene is completed. We will contact you if we need a chef that cooks fusion

Comment: У меня 2 задания input scanner. Не могу пройти из за того что в input                                             
 String FutureProgrammer = scanner.nextLine(); не компилирует ошибку выдает.

Comment: Делайте ввод в конце fusion dishes и после этого нажимайте ввод. Что введете в переменную fusionDishes, то и распечатается в консоле

Comment: я понял спасибо.У меня онлайн компилятор.Я только могу ввести параметры и нажать run.И он не компилирует данную комбинацию и все и ошибка.Консоля здесь нет .

Comment: Может тогда надо сделать две разные переменные fusion и dishes и по другому организовать вывод в консоль? Подправил в ответе выше.

Comment: Failed test #1 of 3. Runtime error

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
 at Main.main(Main.java:14) Вот так теперь получается.Спасибо что со мной возитесь. Я понимаю что Вам это не нужно.Не получается.Хотя intelij работает без проблем.Онлайн компилятор не хочет

Comment: сложно что то ответить, вернитесь к предыдущему варианту и пробуйте в последней переменной ввести fusion dishes. - с точкой, может это и надо онлайн компилятору.

Comment: Я поставлю что вопрос решен .Спасибо Вам за старание. Хотя не работает.